Can I make all src blocks of the same programming language inherit the same #+ATTR_LATEX: block?
Suppose that for Python and only Python, I want #+ATTR_LATEX: :options frame=single to customise my #+begin_src blocks. Does Org Mode have any natural way of doing this?

No - you have to specify #+ATTR_LATEX for every code block of interest by hand. I think there is a duplicate question about this, but I cannot put my finger on it.

Related: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/82337/can-you-set-attr-latex-globally-for-an-entire-document
