Can you set attr_latex globally (for an entire document)?
I've realized that to handle images correctly in org-mode you need both:
#+attr_org: :width 400px
#+attr_latex: :width 10cm
[[./images/image18.png]]

org and latex attributes over EVERY image. org attribute to control display in org mode buffer and latex attribute to control display in pdf output. It would be really nice if you could set them to a default value, ideally per this document (meaning at the top of the document) and then only change them when needed in any particular image.
Is this possible? I couldn't find any way to do that. Perhaps there is some reasonable workaround that isn't having to remember to insert them every time you run export?

Related: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/81287/can-i-make-all-src-blocks-of-the-same-programming-language-inherit-the-same-at

Not possible: these things are examples of Affiliated Keywords and they need to be physically attached (no blank lines) to the element they modify: there is no provision (AFAIK) to set them remotely, whether by global definitions in a file, or properties, or what have you.
I think the best you can do is to use a keyboard macro, function, or template system to define a shortcut  for easy insertion. If you've inserted a ton of them and find out belatedly that you need to modify them, I would do a global search-and-replace.

thank you, that's a shame - I generated a python script to insert attr_latex over links to files (and hopefully only links to files) that don't have it already with some default settings that seemed to work for me (#+attr_latex: :width 10cm :float left): https://pastebin.com/w1qT6qrN . This probably should an elisp script instead. I will have a look at some latex/html templates to do that at export time instead
